# XSLT Conversion consider child not with node value

Tags: html, xml, xslt

below is my XML which consist below nodes.

```
<richtext >
<par def="3">
    paragraph value 1
    <run>
        <font style="underline" />run value 1
    </run>.
    paragraph value 2
    <run>
        <font style="underline" />run value 2
    </run>
    paragraph value 3
    <run>
        <font style="underline" />run value 2 <br /> run value on new line
    </run> 
   paragraph value 4
</par>
</richtext>
```

i am transforming above xml to html using below xslt. i am new to xslt please help me.

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <div>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="richtext" />
</div>
```

```
<xsl:template name="richtext">
<xsl:apply-templates select="par" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="table" />
```

```
<xsl:template match="par">
<p>
  <xsl:if test="text()">
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="text()" />
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="*/following-sibling::text()" />
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="run">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="run" />
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="run/following-sibling::text()" />
  </xsl:if>

</p>
```

```
<xsl:template match="run">
<span>
  <xsl:call-template name="style" />
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="current()" />

</span>
```

i want below html output

```
<p>
    paragraph value 1
    <span style="underline">
        run value 1
    </span>.
    paragraph value 2
    <span style="underline">
        run value 2 <br /> run value on new line
    </span>
    paragraph value 3
    <span style="underline">
        run value 2
    </span> 

   paragraph value 4
</p>
```

Please see updated HTML output. can you please tell me what to do ? i want to preserve style from xml. 
Edit : if we add 
 in XML then i want text after 
 on new line in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to do the following:

1. Convert `richtext` to `div`
2. Convert `par` to `p`
3. Convert `run` to `span`
4. Convert `font` to an attribute

In which case, a series of simple templates should do it.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="richtext">
  <div>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="par|table" />
   </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="par">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates />  
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="run">
  <span>
    <xsl:call-template name="style" />
    <xsl:apply-templates />  
  </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="font" />

<xsl:template name="style">
  <xsl:attribute name="style">
    <xsl:for-each select="font">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">; </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="@style" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the template matching "font" isn't really necessary here. As the `font` elements in your example have no child, you could omit the template as the built-in templates will just skip over it, and output nothing.

Comment: no i don't want that i want to show text linear current output does not showing as per xml with my XSLT. child node getting inserted in one node span

Comment: See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJE . I can't see how the output differs from what you show in your question.

Comment: If @TimC's solution doesn't meet your requirements then you'll have to explain your requirements much more carefully. I'm afraid your comment on his answer is incomprehensible.

Comment: i want to preserve the font tag also.it is important to me to apply style.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to show the actual output you expect. Your current expected output has no font tag. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also edit it to show the template named "style" please?

Comment: that is big one not able to add over here but i am checking the font node attribute and then getting value by name.

Comment: I have amended my answer to show how the font style could be included.

Comment: can't use position as i have to use xslt 1.0

Comment: `position()` is an XSLT 1.0 function. Additionally, my "style" template was just an example because the real "style" template you use is not shown in the question, so I had to guess how it worked.

Comment: thanks i will use this starting point. as my xml come from lotus notes which is heavy . thanks

Comment: @TimC above code not converting <br/> tag from source xml

Comment: can you please help me with this @TimC

Comment: There is no `<br />` in your question, so it is not clear what you want to achieve. You should edit the XML to include a `<br />` element, and the output you expect.

Comment: I've amended my answer to handle `<br />` tags (and potentially other html tags too).

Comment: @TimC can we move this discussion to private chat i have some more question to ask

Comment: I am afraid I don't have time to spend too long on any given question. You might need to ask a whole new question if you have other scenarios that don't work. Sorry.